# RouteProvider in Angular not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I can't get my angular app to route without changing the web page. I'm trying to get the page to change without refreshing and appear in the ng-view, but instead the console is throwing errors. See pastebin for errors http://pastebin.com/kTYwviSv

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/page1.html', {
templateUrl: 'page1.html'

})
.when('/page2.html', {
templateUrl: 'page2.html'

});
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true, requireBase:false});

}]);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Testing Angular On My Own</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
{{"Hello"}}
<br>
<br>

<a ng-href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
<a ng-href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
<div ng-view></div>
<script src="bower_components/bower-angularjs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

page1.html

This is Page 1

page2.html

This is Page 2

Comment: I threw you code in a plunk and it seems to work with no console errors.  https://plnkr.co/edit/PBNB1L76rrt1XeEr8Jli?p=preview

Comment: I see it works in plnkr, but its not doing the same thing for chrome or firefox if you save the files locally to your machine

Comment: Then it is probably related to the location of the html files

Comment: app.js, index.html, page1.html, and page2.html are all in the same directory.

Comment: Is it the way I wrote the routes in app.js?

Comment: Haven't used ngRoute in a few years but I'm wondering if it is particular where the path is concerned.  Perhaps templateUrl: 'page2.html' should be templateUrl: '/{app path}/page2.html'